# Is there a more concise way to indicate many elements that belong to a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

In the article I'm writing I faced the following situation:
∀a∈A, ∀b∈B, ∀c∈C, ∀d∈D, ∀e∈E, ∀f∈F, ∀g∈G, ∀h∈H, ∀i∈I, ∀j∈J, ∀k∈K, ∀l∈L
I end up having to write that line lots of time and this is making the article ugly and cluttered.
Is there a way to condense this notation while still remaining mathematically formal?

Answer (score 4):

Write $Z:=A\times B\times C\times D\times E\times F\times G\times H\times I\times J\times K\times L$ (cartesian product) at the beggining of your article and you will have only to write "$\forall z\in Z$". If you want to detail the name of the componenets write "$\forall(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l)\in Z$".

Comment: I agree with this idea. And you can even make it something like "$\forall (a,b,\ldots,k,l)\in Z$".

Comment: The idea sounds good at first, but there are a few issues. (1) 'a' can only have a value from A, not from any other sets. The way you write, a could belong to B for example, correct? (2) I not always write the domains up to ∀l∈L, sometimes I stop at ∀j∈J and at other times at ∀j∈J. I should have been clearer before, apologies. Any other idea?

Comment: @MartinBalog: (1) No, if $(a,b,\ldots,l)\in A\times B\times\ldots\times L$ then $a\in A$, $b\in B$, …, $l\in L$.

Comment: I think that settles it then. Not that more concise, but enough of an improvement. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe just have sets $X_1,\dots,X_{12}$ and $\forall x_1 \in X_1,\dots, \forall x_{12} \in X_{12} $

This has the benefit of being concise, generalizable (what if you have 100 sets?), and it tells you how many sets there are.